# vue teleport is leading to ts error:Argument of type '{ new (): { $props: VNodeProps & TeleportProps; }; __isTeleport: true; }

Tags: javascript, vue.js

TS2345: Argument of type '{ new (): { $props: VNodeProps & TeleportProps; }; __isTeleport: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VNodeTypes | ClassComponent'.
Type '{ new (): { $props: VNodeProps & TeleportProps; }; __isTeleport: true; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<any, any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions>'.
Types of property '__isTeleport' are incompatible.
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

```
<Teleport to="body">
          <div
            v-show="showMultiSelectWithSearch"
            ref="publisherTypeMultiselect"
            class="multiselect-wrapper"
            :style="multiselectStyle"
          >
            <MultiSelectWithSearch
              header="Publisher Type"
              :list-items="props.publisherTypes"
              @change-selected-publisher="setSelectedPublisher"
            ></MultiSelectWithSearch>
          </div>
        </Teleport>
```